# Bitbucket - denying merge of a branch without an approved pull request

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request

Is there any way in Bitbucket to deny any merge to a specific target branch if that merge is not backed-up by an approved pull request?

Answer (score 2):

In "Repository settings > Branch restrictions > Add a branch restriction (or edit existing) > Merge settings" you can add checks to see specific number of approvals or specific number of approvals from default reviewers, check that no further changes are requested, or you can check for unresolved PR tasks. You can set this up for any specific branch

However preventing merge when there are unresolved merge checks is a premium feature.